# Browser also asks camera permission in ios webview

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, prism, wkwebview

I am having a Xamarin.Forms Prism application. It is using a WKWebView in ios Project to display a web page. In that page, other than the permission from the iOS, a permission popup from browser is also being displayed. Can anybody please help me with this? This is happening only in iOS.

Comment: You said: "other than the permission from the iOS", what permissions have you given? You mean the browser will always pop up asking for camera permission right? Do you want to avoid pop-up windows asking for permission?

Comment: I would like to avoid the pop-up from the browser and keep only the iOS system generated permission pop-up.

Comment: Have you changed the Security and Privacy Features of the application, make sure to add NSCameraUsageDescription in Info.plist. You can refer to the document: [iOS Security and Privacy Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/security-privacy?tabs=windows)

Comment: Yes. It is already added in Info.plist.

Comment: https://nemecek.be/blog/111/wkwebview-improvements-in-ios-15#apis-for-camera-and-microphone

I found out this link which is a new update. But I am not able to use this in my Xamarin. Could anyone please help??

Comment: This one looks like it changes the permissions of WKWebView, you can check the Apple documentation: [Managing the microphone and camera](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview#:~:text=Managing%20the%20microphone%20and%20camera). In xamarin, you need to use it in your Renderer, refer to the code `this.SetCameraCaptureState(WKMediaCaptureState.None, null);`

Comment: This too doesn't seem to work. Can you please give any other method??

Comment: There is a same thread posted at Q&A"[How to fix double permission popup in xamarin ios web view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1167987/how-to-fix-double-permission-popup-in-xamarin-ios)", let's focus on that one.

Comment: Yes. This thread has posted an answer and it helped me... Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1167987/how-to-fix-double-permission-popup-in-xamarin-ios

This thread helped me to solve this problem. Implement a class which is inherited from WKUIDelegate.

```
  public class CustomWebViewDelegate : WKUIDelegate
    {
        [Export("webView:decideMediaCapturePermissionsForOrigin:initiatedByFrame:type:decisionHandler:")]
        public override void RequestMediaCapturePermission(WKWebView webView, WKSecurityOrigin origin, WKFrameInfo frame, WKMediaCaptureType type, Action<WKPermissionDecision> decisionHandler)
        {
            try
            {
                decisionHandler(WKPermissionDecision.Grant);
               base.RequestMediaCapturePermission(webView, origin, frame, type, decisionHandler);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { }
        }
    }
```

Add this statement in the Renderer class.

```
webView.UIDelegate = new CustomWebViewDelegate();
```

Comment: Note that rather than simply granting access, your code should check that the web site that is requesting access is the one you expect; check the request `origin.host` for example

Comment: Not working. First error `Cannot declare conformance to 'NSObjectProtocol' in Swift; 'CustomWebViewDelegate' should inherit 'NSObject' instead`. Second error: `Expected declaration` at line with `[Export("webView:...`

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10032/?time=949

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!;

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView();

        let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration();
        webViewConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;

        webView = WKWebView(frame:.zero , configuration: webViewConfiguration);

        webView.uiDelegate = self;

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();

        webView.load(...);
    }

    @available(iOS 15.0, *)
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
        decideMediaCapturePermissionsFor origin: WKSecurityOrigin,
        initiatedBy frame: WKFrameInfo,
        type: WKMediaCaptureType) async -> WKPermissionDecision {
            return .grant;
    }
}
```